# object refrence not set to an insance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

for any reason i've met an error that is object refrence not set to an instance of an object..

here is my code plz help me out to solve my problem 
thanks in advance..

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()));// this line have such error..

        }
    }

    public void GetUserScraps(int id)
    {
        string getUserScraps = "SELECT r.uid ,r.unm,p.photo,s.uid,s.unm,s.text,s.date,s.sid FROM register as r, status as s, profile as p WHERE p.pid.s.sid AND r.email=p.email AND s.id='" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "'";
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well to start off did you check What is there in `Request.QueryString["id"]` or maybe you misspelled it !

Comment: in which line u get error

Comment: Seems like your url does not have query string `id`

Comment: Where do you initialize the variable dbClass? (I assume that this is not caused by a trivial missing `id` in query string). By the way, why did you pass an integer to the `GetUserScraps` and then you don't use it?

Answer (score 2):

`int.parse` can not handle null and,

Your `Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()` has null value.

Thats why exception is there: `object refrence not set to an insance of an object`

Either check with appropriate value for `Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()` or if it is going to be null in any case then use `convert.toInt()` function which handles null values.

Comment: I guess it would be the `ToString` part failing

Comment: Request.QueryString["id"] this part is null, but if conversion is within convert.toInt then it can be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() has null value.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
             {
                GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()));
             }
        }
     }
    //Here u use id not querystring
    public void GetUserScraps(int id)
    {
        string getUserScraps = "SELECT r.uid ,r.unm,p.photo,s.uid,s.unm,s.text,s.date,s.sid FROM register as r, status as s, profile as p WHERE p.pid.s.sid AND r.email=p.email AND s.id='" + id + "'";
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToString()` instead of `.ToString()` to handle null values, and make sure you are passing `id` query string to this page.

```
string strID=Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["id"]);         
int intID;
if (int.TryParse(strID, out intID))
  { 
    GetUserScraps(intID);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0 && Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
          {
            GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()));// this line have such error..
          }
        }
    }

    public void GetUserScraps(int id)
    {
        string getUserScraps = "SELECT r.uid ,r.unm,p.photo,s.uid,s.unm,s.text,s.date,s.sid FROM register as r, status as s, profile as p WHERE p.pid.s.sid AND r.email=p.email AND s.id='" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "'";
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
        }
 }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your code like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetUserScraps(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));    
        }
    }

    public void GetUserScraps(int id)
    {
        string getUserScraps = "SELECT r.uid ,r.unm,p.photo,s.uid,s.unm,s.text,s.date,s.sid FROM register as r, status as s, profile as p WHERE p.pid.s.sid AND r.email=p.email AND s.id='" + id + "'";
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 GetUserScraps(Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"] ?? "0"));
```